# Serialization of unprintable character

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, .net-4.0, xml-serialization

The following code;

```
var c = (char) 1;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (string));

var writer = new StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(writer, c.ToString()); 
var serialized = writer.ToString();

var dc = serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(serialized));
```

Throws this exception in .NET 4.

> Invalid Operation Exception - There is an error in XML document (2, 12). '', hexadecimal value 0x01, is an invalid character. Line 2, position 12

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there a reasonable work around?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a workaround as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549896/illegal-characters-in-xml-document-in-asp-net-web-service) - you can use [`XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.checkcharacters.aspx) option to ignore validation of characters:

```
XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(serialized),
    new XmlReaderSettings { CheckCharacters = false });
var dc = (string)serializer.Deserialize(xr);
```

Comment: +1 as I wasn't aware of it, but I think it's worth stressing that you'll end up with invalid XML. If anything else in your data pipeline relies on valid XML, it will break.

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to serialize characters which can't be represented within XML. Unfortunately they break XML serialization. I don't know of any workarounds for this other than writing your own escaping code.

On the other hand, actual uses for such characters (ASCII characters before space, other than tab, carriage return and line feed IIRC) are relatively rare - you may find you're okay just to strip them. Alternatives are to come up with your own escaping, or encode the whole string as binary and base64 the result. Escaping will take a good deal less space than the re-encoding approach :)

Comment: Yes, if you are at the point where these characters are significant, it's time to  stop treating it as text. It's binary.

Comment: Thanks @JonSkeet, just in case it's of interest I'm trying to serialize an object which contains a standard [FIX message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Financial_Information_eXchange#FIX_message_format_layout) in a string field within it. They use SOH / (char)1 as a delimiter. I appreciate your point about this being invalid XML but this is just a small side project so I'm going to be pragmatic and use the approach below. Thanks!