# Invalid Unicode Character in XML string

Tags: c#, xml, unicode

I have XML string and when I try to add it to Word Custom XML Part it throws exception: Invalid Unicode Character. I have nothing unusual in this long string, excep 2 questionable characters in a few places:

```xml
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">1.1.1.1.2.1   This Checklist is based upon the UCF Control [ UCF CC ID 00785 ] entitled Train all personnel and third parties, as necessary.
&#xB;The organization must properly train all IT personnel. This document serves as a checklist for the items that must be thought through and made part of any IT personnel training program.</Cell>
```

and

```xml
<Cell xsi:type="xsd:string">1.2   © 2022 - Network Frontiers LLC  / www.commoncontrolshub.com **&#x7**;</Cell>
```

Are those allowed?

Comment: This: `&#x7` is not legal. I don't know if you need 2 or 4 hex digits, but I'm 99% sure you can't have just one

Comment: Upload your XML to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will get an error, *`Character reference "&#xB" is an invalid XML character.`* and *`The character reference must end with the ';' delimiter.`*.

Comment: @dbc: I suspect the latter of those errors is due to the OP adding asterisks to attempt to highlight the problematic part.

Comment: You can see the Unicode character ranges allowed by XML in the [XML Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Char): `Char    ::=    #x9 | #xA | #xD | [#x20-#xD7FF] | [#xE000-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#x10FFFF]`.  `#xB` and `#x7` are not included.

Comment: Or `#x7` (which is the bell character IIRC - odd to include in a document).

Comment: If you really need to read such XML, you can set [`XmlReaderSettings.CheckCharacters = false`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.checkcharacters) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6020608/3744182) by [mellamokb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116614/mellamokb) to [Serialization of unprintable character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6020441/3744182).  In fact this might be a duplicate, agree?  (Might be better to ask your XML provider to fix their XML though.)

Comment: The answer from dbc is correct!